# Solve the system of equations? What is this format of an answer?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

So I solved this system without using matrices, just by (sort of) reverting to high school math instincts.
$$w+x=-5$$
$$x+y=4$$
$$y+z=1$$
$$w+z=8$$
From this, I got $w=-9,x=4,y=0$ and $z=1$. How would I convert this back to what appears to be a matrix form?

Comment: $w=-9$,  I think.

Comment: @aero26: did you try RREF? The answer becomes obvious.

Comment: I am sorry but what is 's' here? sign?

Comment: @aero26, the solution you've found is not the only possible solution. There are many solutions to this system of equations. You need to fill in the numbers so that for every value of $s$ you get a valid solution.

Comment: you have $w+z = -8$ in one set of equations and $w+z = 8$ in the other.  The equations are not linearly independent, so you will get either a range of solutions, or an inconsistent solution depending on what $w+z$ equals.  since we are expecting at least a line of solutions, set one of $\{x,y,z,w\}$ equal to $s$ and solve for the rest in terms of $s.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the format, you get that $x_i=a_i+s*b_i$

$x_1+x_2=-5 => a_1+a_2+s(b_1+b_2) = -5$ for all s. Thus, $b_1=-b_2$

Similarly, you get $b_1=-b_2=b_3=-b_4$

The solution you got is for $a_1, a_2,a_3,a_4$

Thus, 
$x_1 = -9+s*1$ (taking $b$ into $s$)

$x_2=4+s*(-1)$

$x_3=0+s*(1)$

$x_4=1+s*(-1)$

Answer (score 0):

In the equations, you have four variables, *x1*, *x2*, *x3*, and *x4*. The challenge is to 1) solve for each, and 2) state them in terms of some single constant s, instead of the other variables.
The first step is to solve for each of the variables, which will result in this:

$x_1 = -5 - x_2$

$x_2 = 4 - x_3$

$x_3 = 1 - x_4$

$x_4 = -8 - x_1$

Now we need to put these in terms of $s$. So, arbitrarily set $x_1$ to $s$.

Thus, $x_4$ can be restated:

$x_4 = 8 - s$

And then you can restate $x_3$ using the updated $x_4$:

$x_3 = 1 - (-8 - s)$

And simplify to:

$x_3 = 9 + s$

Now you can restate $x_2$ using the updated $x_3$ in the same way:

$x_2 = 4 - (9 + s)$

And simplify to:

$x_2 = -5 - s$

Restate $x_1$ using the updated $x_2$ in the same way:

$x_1 = -5 - (-5 - s)$

And simplify to:

$x_1 = 0 + s$

Our four simplified equations in terms of s are:

$x_1 = 0 + s$

$x_2 = -5 - s$

$x_3 = 9 + s$

$x_4 = 8 - s$

Which can be formatted in the way of the solution as:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
x_4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
$=$
$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
-5 \\
9 \\
8 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
$ + s$
$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
-1 \\
1 \\
-1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Answer (score -2):

[image]

i guess that answers your question